# Why is my object variable considered null?

Tags: java

In my method answer(), it will say that my variable is null. I do not understand why because it refers to the RandNum object which has values of (min, max). The method is basically supposed to return the sum, difference, quotient, or product depending on the variable type. It does this with the two objects and is supposed to return that value.

```
public class Problem {

private String type;
private int min, max;
private RandNum first, second;


public Problem(String type, int min, int max){
    this.type = type;
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    generateNumbers();
}

private void generateNumbers(){
    RandNum first = new RandNum(min, max);
    RandNum second = new RandNum(min, max);
}

public double answer(){
    if(type.equals("+")){
        return first.getValue() + second.getValue();
    }
    else if(type.equals("-")){
        return first.getValue() - second.getValue();
    }
    else if(type.equals("*")){
        return first.getValue() * second.getValue();
    }
    return first.getValue() / second.getValue();
}

}


public class RandNum {

private int value;

public RandNum(int min, int max)
{
    value = (int)(Math.random()*(max + 1 -min)) + min;
}

public int getValue()
{
    return value;
}
}
```

Comment: Your `generateNumbers` method assigns values to *local variables* `first` and `second` - you don't really want to be declaring local variables, you want to assign values to the *fields* `first` and `second`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have **shadowed** the fields by declaring local variables of the same name, that immediately leave scope. This,

```
private void generateNumbers(){
    RandNum first = new RandNum(min, max);
    RandNum second = new RandNum(min, max);
}
```

should be

```
private void generateNumbers(){
    this.first = new RandNum(min, max);
    this.second = new RandNum(min, max);
}
```